# my project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I wanted to move my project into Android Studio and when I was running the simulator, the project was running fine. Since I updated Android Studio, the simulator has the error that the Gradle version of the project is not compatible with the Java version.

I would like to know how I can fix the problem gradle version of my project with version 6.8.3 and the compatible version of java version of my PC, I can't find the compatible version of Java with my project that it could work right I think, because of I upgraded my android studio with it upgraded Java too and I can't it downgrade again, I wish that you understood now.

**Setup**:

Gradle 6.8.3
Java 17
Flutter 3.7.12
Android Studio 2022.2.1

**Error Message**:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '.\android\settings.gradle' (.\.gradle\caches\6.8.3\scripts\9w4vzv9io97x5h1yfb63h0ld4).
 > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 61

To fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running flutter doctor --verbose. Then, update the Gradle version specified in .\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with that Java version.
```

**Output from `java --version`**:

```
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It would be recommendable to mention the versions of the products you are using. And the errors. Have you tried changing the version of Gradle or Java to make them compatible? Have you read the requirements of each product?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the version of gradle and Java and it to downgrade but I couldn't fix it, every time came the same problem, if  you have good intruction that I fix it, please write me

Comment: The version of gradle in project is 6.8.3 and the version of Java is 17

Comment: You need to provide the rest of the information to help others to help you. Versions of Flutter, Android Studio, etc, errors, configurations.

Comment: Flutter version 3.7.12, Android Studio version flamingo 2022.2.1, FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Source\pizzaboy\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Gholamreza\.gradle\caches\6.8.3\scripts\9w4vzv9io97x5h1yfb63h0ld4).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

Comment: * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Comment: To fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter doctor    │
│ --verbose`.                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                   │
│ C:\Source\pizzaboy\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with that │
│ Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:

Comment: it has this problem just by this project because of gradle version and java version

Comment: I wrote this command incmd for java -version and then
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Comment: please write me how to change java version correct

Comment: Please edit your question and add the details in a way that's understandable. It is very difficult to track comments and they lack proper order and formatting.

Comment: I would like to know how I can fix the problem gradle version of my project with version 6.8.3 and the compatible version of java version of my PC, I can't find the compatible version of Java with my project that it could work right I think, because of I upgraded my android studio with it upgraded Java too and I can't it downgrade again, I wish that you understood now.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the missing information from the comments.

Answer (score 10):

As you are using **java 17**, then upgrade **gradle** to *version 7.3* at least.
get idea from [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).
You can also get version idea from [Gradle Release](https://gradle.org/releases/)

Go to

- Step 1: Go to the gradle directory for your project:

  cd android/gradle/wrapper
- Step 2: Edit the gradle-wrapper.properties file to change the distribution Url field to the preferred Gradle version (7.3 or others):

  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip

Happy Fixing!

Comment: works like abaracadabra

Answer (score 1):

on your ide project explored
Go to android->gradle(not .gradle)->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties

and change distribution to `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip`

or you can change gradle-7.6.1-all to the latest gradle version

Answer (score 0):

Change on latest gradle will work

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-Latest version-all.zip
```

Example: `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip`