# Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for gradle

Tags: java, flutter, dart, gradle

[Debug error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrvpW.png)

I have tried to delete the version in gradle folder and run debug again still the same error message.
Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78) and My gradle version is: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
android studio version 34, Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable, Dart version 3.0.6

Comment: Did you tried `flutter doctor --verbose`? you could get hint from that command.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798266/the-project-uses-gradle-2-10-which-is-incompatible-with-android-studio-2020-3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123807/my-projects-gradle-version-is-incompatible-with-the-java-version-that-flutter-i

Comment: check these post to get your answer. You have to upgrade your gradle version . see some videos if not understand .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76795890/flutter-warning-when-build-release/76825418#76825418 
can you try this ?

Answer (score -1):

Your gradle is not compatible with your java version.
Just follow the error message, then you can find compatible version for gradle or java, after that update it !