FAILURE: Build failed with an exception error
i am running my demo flutter project on my real device in vs code. but i face an issue. i have enable debugging mode etc and there is no issue in flutter doctor sdk etc but when i start debugging  it shows that msg in debugging output section.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'E:\flutter_application_1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\8.3\scripts\c7e83kw3632xi74ah5hvg8xdk).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 67

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.




Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using   │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                     │
│                                                                                                 │
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                         │
│ https://flutter.dev/to/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                                          │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter │
│ doctor --verbose`.                                                                              │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                    │
│ E:\flutter_application_1\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with │
│ that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:  │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                               │
2
│                                                                                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Hello, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123807/my-projects-gradle-version-is-incompatible-with-the-java-version-that-flutter-i

This question is similar to: my project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

U talk about android studio while I mention   Vs code . In which   the real  device when I wanna to run gives that. Error please  in Vs code how  we remove such kind of issues  . If u have solid answer. Help .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
